# How to avoid nested for loop in this apex code?

Tags: apex, batch, callout, loop

```
public class TestUserData {
public static HttpResponse makeApiCallout(String endpointUrl){
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    App_Id__mdt appid = App_Id__mdt.getInstance('appid');
    
    //system.debug(appid);
    String apiAppId = appid.API_app_id__c;
    String endpointUrls = appid.endPointUrl__c;    
    request.setEndpoint(endpointUrls+endpointUrl);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    
    //system.debug(APPI);   
    request.setHeader('app-id', apiAppId);
    
    
    Http http = new Http();
    return http.send(request);   
}
public static void importDummyApiData() {
    // Make HTTP callout to dummyapi.io API
    String endpointUrl = 'user';
    HttpResponse response = makeApiCallout(endpointUrl);
    // Parse the API response and create custom object records
    List<Api_User__c> customObjects = new List<Api_User__c>();
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        List<Object> userData = (List<Object>) jsonResponse.get('data');
        for (Object user : userData) {
            Map<String, Object> userMap = (Map<String, Object>) user;
            Api_User__c customObject = new Api_User__c();
            customObject.Name = (String) userMap.get('id');
            customObject.Title__c = (String) userMap.get('title');
            customObject.first_name__c = (String) userMap.get('firstName');
            customObject.Last_Name__c = (String) userMap.get('lastName');
            customObject.picture__c = (String) userMap.get('picture');
            customObjects.add(customObject);
        }
        System.debug(customObjects);
        insert customObjects;
    }
}
public static void importUserPosts() {
    // Fetch API user data to map user IDs to Salesforce record IDs
    Map<String, Id> apiUserIdsMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    List<Api_User__c> apiUsers = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Api_User__c];
    List<User_Post__c> posts = new List<User_Post__c>();
    //system.debug(apiUsers);
    for (Api_User__c apiUser : apiUsers) {
        apiUserIdsMap.put(apiUser.Name, apiUser.Id);
        String endpointUrl = 'user/'+apiUser.Name+'/post';
        //System.debug(endpointUrl+'jiii');
        HttpResponse response = makeApiCallout(endpointUrl);
       
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            List<Object> postData = (List<Object>) jsonResponse.get('data');
            System.debug('Dataaa'+ postData);
            for (Object post : postData) {
                Map<String, Object> postMap = (Map<String, Object>) post;
                Map<String, Object> owner = (Map<String, Object>)postMap.get('owner');
                String userId = (String) owner.get('id');
                //System.debug(userId);
                String tags = String.valueOf(postMap.get('tags'));
                if (apiUserIdsMap.containsKey(userId)) {
                    User_Post__c postRecord = new User_Post__c();
                    postRecord.Id__c = (String) postMap.get('id');
                    postRecord.Image__c = (String) postMap.get('image');
                    postRecord.likes__c = (Integer) postMap.get('likes');
                    postRecord.Tag__c = tags;
                    postRecord.Name = (String) postMap.get('text');
                    postRecord.Publish_Date__c = (String) postMap.get('publishDate');
                    postRecord.Owner_Id__c = apiUser.Id;
                    posts.add(postRecord);
                }
            }
            system.debug(posts);
        }
    }insert posts;
}
```

}

Comment: I am trying to to resolve the nested for loop issue  in importUserPosts() method can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested loops are bad when they do something like this:

```
Account[] accounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account];
Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Name, AccountId FROM Contact];
for(Account accountRecord: accounts) {
  for(Contact contactRecord: contacts) {
    if(contactRecord.AccountId == accountRecord.Id) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

These are wasteful loops. Compare that to the following:

```
Account[] accounts = [SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account];
for(Account accountRecord: accounts) {
  for(Contact contactRecord: accountRecord.Contacts) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This loop is not wasteful, because each contact is processed only in context of their account record.

The same thing is going on here. The nested loop appears to be appropriate for your use case. You're going over a list of records returned for a user, so you must have a nested loop, or collect the data for separate processing. Here's what that probably looks like:

```
public static void importUserPosts() {
    Map<String, Id> apiUserIdsMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    List<Api_User__c> apiUsers = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Api_User__c];
    List<Object> posts = new List<Object>();
    List<User_Post__c> apiUserPosts = new List<User_Post__c>();
    for (Api_User__c apiUser : apiUsers) {
        apiUserIdsMap.put(apiUser.Name, apiUser.Id);
        String endpointUrl = 'user/'+apiUser.Name+'/post';
        HttpResponse response = makeApiCallout(endpointUrl);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            List<Object> postData = (List<Object>) jsonResponse.get('data');
            posts.addAll(postData);
        }
    }
    for (Object post : posts) {
        Map<String, Object> postMap = (Map<String, Object>) post;
        Map<String, Object> owner = (Map<String, Object>)postMap.get('owner');
        String userId = (String) owner.get('id');
        if (apiUserIdsMap.containsKey(userId)) {
            User_Post__c postRecord = new User_Post__c();
            postRecord.Id__c = (String) postMap.get('id');
            postRecord.Image__c = (String) postMap.get('image');
            postRecord.likes__c = (Integer) postMap.get('likes');
            postRecord.Tag__c = String.valueOf(postMap.get('tags'));
            postRecord.Name = (String) postMap.get('text');
            postRecord.Publish_Date__c = (String) postMap.get('publishDate');
            postRecord.Owner_Id__c = userId;
            apiUserPosts.add(postRecord);
        }
    }
    insert apiUserPosts;
}
```

As you can see, nothing really changes, except you're holding on to data longer than you need to (more heap memory used), but that's largely irrelevant. You're not going to save much/any CPU time, so the nested loop is actually ideal here.

Comment: Thank you for answering

Comment: postRecord.Owner_Id__c = apiUser.Id;
this line is giving error because apiUser is variable of first for loop. You have any other solution for this? because without Owner_Id__c i can't able to insert any record because it is master-detail relation between Api_User__c and User_Post__c.

Comment: @sahilkakadiya I think I meant it to be `postRecord.Owner_Id__c = userId;` since that is ultimately what you're reading in your original code. There was some other incomplete code in there. I've edited to be (hopefully) correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. that means a lot to me @sfdcfox

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to avoid nested loops in this code. The nested loops are not creating a multiplicative impact on performance, because you’re *only iterating over each record once*.

Nested loops are inefficient when you iterate over lots of data that you do not need to process in order to find data you do need to process. I’ve written a much longer [discussion](https://ktema.org/articles/quick-look-computational-complexity-apex/) of this topic with several examples.

Your code isn’t optimal, though. In particular, you need to get that DML out of the loop. And the most efficient code will be possible only if the API you are calling can be bulkified. Calling it once per record locks you into a very inefficient pattern, and you do risk hitting the Apex callout limits here. To scale, you’ll likely want to refactor into a Queueable-based automation.

Comment: Thank you for answering